# How to have multiple conditions in a named scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope, named-scope, rails-models

I have a User model. I can check whether a User is an admin by doing `a_user.try(:admin?)`.

I'd like to define a named scope that gets all Users updated within the last X minutes who are *not* admins. So far I have:

```
scope :recent, lambda { { :conditions => ['updated_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago] } }
```

This successfully gets all Users updated within the last 5 minutes, but how do I incorporate the admin check? I don't know how to call `try()` on an instance of a User inside the scope...

Comment: I think this question is partially answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352860/rails-named-scopes-conditional-conditions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352860/rails-named-scopes-conditional-conditions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if admin column in users table is a boolean,

```
scope :recent, lambda { :conditions => ['updated_at > ? AND admin != ?', 5.minutes.ago, true] }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I had to change `&&` to `AND` because it was giving me syntax errors. I also used `true` instead of `1`, just because it's more readable.

Answer (score 15):

Just another possibility, usable in Rails 4,

```
scope :recent, -> { where('updated_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago }
# If you were using rolify, you could do this
scope :non_admin, -> { without_role :admin }
# given the OP question,
scope :non_admin, -> { where(admin: false) }
scope :non_admin_recent, -> { non_admin.recent }
```

This is just another possible format and taking in account the possibility of using Rolify gem.

Comment: So THAT's how you chain scopes! Thank you! Brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `lambda`, I find it cleaner to use class methods.

```
def self.recent
  where('updated_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago)
end

def self.admin
  where(admin: true)
end

def self.recent_and_admin
  recent.admin # or where('updated_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago).where(admin: true)
end
```