# Rails Scope with Multiple Conditions on itself and nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app, the class Project is defined as follows:

```
has_many :spins
has_one :video
```

I'd like to create a scope for Project that returns all projects that meet the following conditions:

```
project.video.present? || project.spins.count > 0 && project.spins.first.default_video.present?
```

I've read about how to use [multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623668/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-in-a-named-scope) in a scope, but I'm unsure about how to combine this with a conditional on a nested attribute (in this case, spins).

How do I create a scope for Project that meets these conditions?

*Edit*:
For clarification, *default_video* is a class method for Spin:

```
def default_video
    self.videos.where("has_audio IS NULL").first
end
```

Comment: I can help you a little bit for the first two conditions. For the first one, don't check present, but `WHERE videos.project_id (or projects.video_id) not NULL`. The second one is `WHERE COUNT('spins.id') > 0`. I don't know about the last one, since I don't really understand the relationship that is going on and don't know if you can use the .first part.

Comment: what's the default_video in spin : a column value, an association ? Do you have eventually a Spin#default_video_id ?

Comment: do videos have a spin_id column ? it's difficult to come up with a solution without a clear schema of your tables...

Comment: any luck with either one of the answers ?

Answer (score 1):

As I know ActiveRecord does not provide the feature merging scopes with OR ( for the moment).
I think there is two options to deal with this feature :

1 - Create a scope that returns projects containing a video or with a first spin containing a default video :

```
scope :with_video, -> { joins(
  'LEFT JOIN spins 
    ON spins.id = (
      select p.id
      from spins as p WHERE projects.id = p.project_id ORDER BY p.id LIMIT 1
    )
   JOIN videos on videos.project_id = projects.id 
   WHERE 
     spins.default_video IS NOT NULL 
   OR 
     videos.project_id IS NOT NULL
')
```

}

I think this solution is unreadable and it's difficult to maintain. I do not make some performance tests with this query, perhaps this one must be improved

2 - create 2 scopes and merge both results

```
scope :with_one_video, -> { joins(:videos) }
scope :with_spin_video, -> { joins('JOIN spins ON 
  spins.id = ( 
    SELECT S.id
    FROM spins as S 
    WHERE projects.id = S.project_id 
    ORDER BY S.id LIMIT 1
  )').where('spins.default_video IS NOT NULL')}

def with_video
  (with_one_video.to_a + with_spin_video.to_a).uniq
end
```

This one is better with reusable scopes but the second scope is still difficult to read. With this solution results has been return as an Array, it can be a disadvantage depending on the situation.

Edit: I'm interrested by all answers with differents solutions, improvments on sql queries or even replaced them by activerecord / arel

Comment: Isn't the where(not null) clause unnecessary since rails joins are inner joins?

Comment: Exact ! on with_one_video scope the clause where is not necessary. Thanks

Comment: I gave it a try with grouping by, but didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition is fairly easy since rails `joins` are inner Joins so it excludes non existant associations :

```
Project.joins(:video)
```

The second condition could be written this way (provided default_video is column of spins table) :

```
Project.joins(:spins).
        group("spins.project_id").
        having("count(spins.default_video) > 0")
```

Unfortunately they don't work well together.

Instead I propose 2 left outer joins (keeping all projects) and then `group by project.id`. That'll "compress" all the joins in one row and from there we check for nulls by counting some of the joined columns.

```
 Project.joins("left join videos on videos.project_id = project.id").
         joins("left join spins on spins.project_id = project.id").
         group("projects.id").
         having("count(videos.project_id) > 0 OR count(spins.default_video) > 0")
```

**Edit** : Based on additional informations we need one more join : the one tying `videos` to `spin` (as for the `default_video` which is an association).

```
 Project.joins("left join videos on videos.project_id = project.id").
         joins("left join spins on spins.project_id = project.id").
         joins("inner join videos s_vid on s_vid.spin_id = spins.id").
         group("projects.id").
         having("count(videos.project_id) > 0 OR count(s_vid.spin_id) > 0").
         select("projects.*)
```