# Scope conditionals for count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope, count

How can I get this `scope` to work with multiple `.count`?

```
scope :level_5, -> { (self.accomplished.key.count > 4) && (self.accomplished.adventure.count > 2)
&& (self.accomplished.health.count > 2) && (self.accomplished.work.count > 2) }
```

I've also tried:

```
scope :level_5, -> { self.accomplished.key.count > 4, self.accomplished.adventure.count > 2,
self.accomplished.health.count > 2), (self.accomplished.work.count > 2) }
```

or

```
scope :level_5, -> { accomplished.where(key.count > 4, adventure.count > 2,
health.count > 2, work.count > 2) }
```

or

```
scope :level_5, -> { "user.accomplished.key.count > 4" && "user.accomplished.adventure.count > 2" &&
"user.accomplished.health.count > 2" && "user.accomplished.work.count > 2" }
```

It will be used for conditionals so if `:level_5` then trigger X.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623668/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-in-a-named-scope

Comment: Scope are used to construct database queries. I am not sure if all this values exist in the database or need to be calculated. Therefore: What is `accomplished`? Another scope, how is it defined? What are `key`, `health` and `work`? Columns in the database? It might help if you show how your database looks like, some example records and the expected result.